# In a C# Web Method is it possible to store data retrieved via Entity Framework for subsequent calls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a web method that accesses about 8 tables from the database via EF6. The web method will be called every time the user changes an option on the form, so that other inputs of the form reflect what is possible based on current selections.

The tables themselves will rarely change, but the web method may be hit 10 - 12 times per user.

A simplified version of my web method would be:

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetProducts() {

    string output = "";

    using (var context = new MyEntity.MyEntities())
    {
        foreach (MyEntity.MyProduct p in context.MyProducts)
        {
            /// Perform some logic here to decide if we want the product

            output += p.MyProductName + "_";
        }
    }

    if (output != "")
        output = output.Substring(0, output.Length - 1);

    return output;
}
```

In this simplified example is it possible to cache the products table once in a manner that the asmx can use for subsquent calls and then just use that rather than keep hitting the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [WebMethodAttribute.CacheDuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webmethodattribute.cacheduration%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to cache the result of web method.

> When caching is enabled requests and responses are held in memory on
>   the server for at least the cache duration so caution must be used if
>   you expect requests or responses to be very large or you expect
>   requests to vary widely.

```
[WebMethod(CacheDuration = 180)]
public string GetProducts() {
```

There are two issues that can affect output caching in an ASP.NET 2.0 Web service application.

- In ASP.NET 2.0 the HTTP method of the test page has changed from GET to POST. However, POSTs are not normally cached. If you change the test page in an ASP.NET 2.0 Web service application to use GET, caching works properly.
- In addition, HTTP indicates that a user agent (the browser or calling application) should be able to override server caching by setting the "Cache-Control" to "no-cache". ASP.NET applications, therefore, ignore cached results when they find a "no-cache" header.